# Questions about an "almost" 4-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, hamiltonian-path

How would this graph be classified? And what properties does it have? What would be a natural thing to study with this graph? I know it has **40** nodes. It's undirected. It's planar if I'm not mistaken. Also this graph looks like it's **4**-connected except for the **4** outer most nodes.

I read on Wikipedia that: "**4**-connected planar graphs are always Hamiltonian by a result due to Tutte, and the computational task of finding a Hamiltonian cycle in these graphs can be carried out in linear time." Are **4**-connected planar graphs somehow easier to compute Hamiltonian cycles for?

I'm wondering if that result is valid for this graph because **4** nodes have degree **6**, while the others have degree **4**. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: It is very easy to find a Hamiltonian cycle in this graph. First find a cycle in the inner 6x6 grid graph. Then replace four of the outer edges with detours to the 4 extreme nodes.

Comment: Or add four edges to the outside connecting the extreme nodes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - that would be changing the graph. I'm talking about finding a Hamiltonian cycle in the exact graph you pictured. If you want to to ask about a different graph, you should ask a different question.